# Installing CoGrOO on Kile

Tags: libreoffice, ide, kile

Does anyone know if it is possible to install/include CoGrOO on Kile?

CoGroo: http://cogroo.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Kile? The link refers to an add-on for LibreOffice.

Comment: Yes, The link refers to an add-on for LibreOffice. I seek some way to add this corrector in Kile.

Comment: That would be off-topic, since it has nothing to do with TeX - LaTeX.

Comment: Instead of closing, this could be in topic for Unix & Linux, maybe should be migrated there?

Comment: Ok,I like this?

Comment: The OP seems to agree that the post should be migrated to unix.SE.